# Uploading iOS 7 app to Apple App Store Error

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, xcode5

Needing some help. I have an iOS 7 app developed in Xcode 5, but everytime I go to upload the build to the app store I get the following error. 
"This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of SDK, Xcode." 
So they give us the tools to develop but we can't upload the app?  Any way to fix this would be a HUGE help. Thank you

Comment: Did you download the GM seed version?

Comment: The xcode or ios GM?  I got Xcode 5.0 two weeks ago so i might need to update to the GM seed of xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not uploading build through XCode5 Preview.You will not get this error in XCode5 alpha version that is released right after iPhone5s.